# Securely using JSON web tokens to programmatically authenticate a user from one system into another

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, jwt, authorization

My team and I have been working on a web application for our clients that uses JSON web tokens for authentication and authorization. Using Azure AD as our identity provider, we verify a user's identity and generate a signed JWT with the user's permissions in it. The JWT then gets included in the authorization header of all subsequent requests to the APIs. Pretty standard stuff as far as JWTs go.

We're now being asked to provide the capability to link directly into our system from another third-party web application without forcing the user to reauthenticate. I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to do so without creating a massive security loophole.

The way I picture this working would be to implement an endpoint for programmatic authentication in our system that accepts a cryptographically signed payload with an API key and the user's ID or email address. The third-party system would have a private key with which to sign the payload, and we'd have a public one to verify the signature. If the request is legitimate, we'd issue a token for the specified user, and they could use that to link to whatever they like.

I'm already getting yelled at by at least one person that this is a complete joke from a security standpoint because, among other things, it completely bypasses AAD authentication. I believe the third-party system in question does use AAD for authentication, but that's not really relevant either way because we're trusting them implicitly whether they've authenticated their users or not. Either way I take his point.

I'm not a security expert and I don't claim to know whether there even is a proper way to do this kind of thing, but from my vantage it doesn't really seem all that much less secure than any other mechanism of authentication and authorization using JWTs. Is that true? Are we nuts for even trying? Is there a way to do it that's more secure? What should I know about this that I demonstrably don't already?

Thanks in advance for the help. At the very least I hope this spurs some helpful conversation.

Answer (score 0):

Single Sign-On (SSO) enables users to enter their credentials once to sign in and establish a session which can be reused across multiple applications without requiring to authenticate again. This provides a seamless experience to the user and reduces the repeated prompts for credentials.
Azure AD provides SSO capabilities to applications by setting a session cookie when the user authenticates the first time. The MSAL.js library allows applications to leverage this in a few ways.

MSAL relies on the session cookie to provide SSO for the user between different applications.

Read more in this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-sso).